# What to do with 500 78L05's?

Tags: voltage-regulator

I got 500 78L05's. Does anybody have a suggestion for an interesting circuit which uses a lot of 78L05's? Or is it not really possible to do anything more interesting than simple voltage and current regulating circuits with them?

Comment: Sell them on ebay, buy more interesting components?

Comment: Other classic ICs (TL431, NE555, UA741) can be used for tons of interesting projects in a lot of different ways. IMHO, the 78xx/79xx series is rather boring, in comparison, because it can only be used for its one intended purpose of being a plain old voltage regulator. However, it is quite good at doing just that...

Comment: Post a picture, would like to see how big of a heap it is :)

Comment: I'm thinking *Art Installation*.

Comment: @zebonaut: Yes, I have played around with 555's and 741's. I was just wondering if something interesting could be made out of 78L05's as well. I couldn't think of anything interesting.

Comment: @s3c: Haha, not that big: http://i.stack.imgur.com/4ViCn.jpg

Comment: Thermal relaxation oscillator?

Comment: About the only creative misuse of linear regulators I've heard is that they can make RF oscillators. Can't think what you'd do with 500 of them, though.

Comment: @BrianDrummond especially 79xx is instable without caps, you can often get away wit a cap-less 78xx.

Comment: Design something that uses a single 78L05 -> sell 500 of them -> profit!

Answer (score 1):

Best idea is sell it.. You don't need that much linear regulators for any circuit unless you are manufacturing bulk boards..